# Can't create multiple Cosmos MongoDB collections at the same time

Tags: terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

Trying to create two Collections at the same time throws me this error:

```
The specified type system value 'TypedJsonBson' is invalid.
```

Judging by the response log, and the fact that the error is occurring at the `apply` phase, I suspect it is something with the API.

Samples:

- Configuration to simulate the problem: [main.tf](https://gist.github.com/evandropomatti/39821ae642dcc0804e467bf7f7fd853b)
- Terraform logs:  [run-pAXmLixNWWimiHNs-apply-log.txt](https://gist.github.com/evandropomatti/b4153265fcb70f2b1949fe2b794f2b39)

---

### Workaround

It is possible to avoid this problem by creating one Collection at a time.

```
depends_on = [
  azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_collection.example
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your terraform `main.tf` files on my local PowerShell, it works fine. So the terraform configuration file should be correct.

[image]

I would suggest running `terraform apply` on the [Azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview). You could remove the old `terraform.tfstate` file and `.terraform` folder and re-run `terraform init` locally or verify other reasons on your working environment.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if Terraform has a means to specify that parent resources need to exist before child resources can be created then you should use this because ARM requires this for any resource to be created.

Comment: I am creating two Collections at the same time. It is not a parent-child relationship.

Comment: Using Azure CLI no problems to create two collections at the same time. I'll try more scenarios tomorrow.